# How to get Outlook 2013 to show Skype account for IM

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype

I have Outlook 2013 linked to my Windows Account, which is in turn linked to my Skype account. If I click my Windows Account in Outlook, it takes me to a page where I can view my Skype friends list, messages, profile, etc.
However, in the address bar when I click on my name it has my IM info tied to my exchange email address, which is not related to any of this. I can't find a setting anywhere in exchange for changing the IM account, nor in Outlook. Everything is linked up properly, it's like it's defaulting the IM account in Outlook to the exchange email address rather than any kind of linked Windows/Skype accounts. Is this configurable?